# squid configuartion on MAC OSX lion

Tags: mac-osx, squid

I have installed and configured squid in MAC OS X lion.

It is working fine (when running ./squid it is not returning error) but not sure is it caching the content or not.

My target is to setup PROXY CACHE in my local MAC system so that the web documents are returned from the proxy cache.
My basic configuration is as follows:

```
cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache 500 16 256
acl my_machine src 192.168.1.108
http_port 192.168.1.105:3128 transparent
```

http_access allow my_machine

Is their any special configuration needed to set up the cache?And any command that we reload the squid.conf files?

Any article link to setup proxy cache server using squid will be the best for me.

Comment: When I am going to http://localhost:3128/ it is showing error "ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved" .

Comment: Did you ever get this straightened out?  If not; please include what version of Squid you're running and the squid.config file.